# Ruby: Green_shoes, assign list_box selection to a variable

Tags: ruby, variables, user-interface, shoes

I'm using Ruby/green_shoes to create a gui application.
I want the user to be able to select a com port and then press a button to run the script.

It's nearly done, however I can't seem to take the highlighted com port and assign it to the variable 'port' so that it can be passed to my script when I press the button.

```
para "Select your COM port: "
list_box items: ["COM1", "COM2", "COM3", "COM4", "COM5", "COM6", "COM7", "COM8", "COM9", "COM10"], width: 120
@push = button "Begin Patching Process"
@push.click {
serial = SerialPort.new("#{port}", 9600)
serial.read_timeout = 200
serial.write("\x50\xBB\xFF\x01\x25\x98\x4D") #contains initialization to program
serial.readlines
serial.write("\x02") #requests firmware version
serial.readlines
serial.write("\x06")
serial.readlines
serial.write("\x58\x1f\xc0\x10\x00\x00\x00\x02\x02\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x34\x01\x80\x00") #contains VHF freqs (\x01\x34\x01\x80)
serial.readlines
serial.write("\x06\x58\x1f\xd0\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x04\x00\x05\x20\x00") #contains UHF freqs (x01\x04\x00\x05\x20)
serial.readlines
serial.write("\x06\x58\x1e\xe0\x10\x20\x20\x56\x46\x4f\x20\x20\x55\x4e\x4c\x4f\x43\x4b\x20\x00\x00") #contains pwr on msg (ASCII)
}
end
```

There is of course more code after this containing what to do when the button is pushed.

I just need to have it so that when I select COM7 for example.... the variable 'port' is equal to that selected com port from the list.

Working revisions below thanks to accepted answer @7stud

```
Shoes.app title: "BFB-251 VFO Patcher", width: 420, height: 120 do
background gray
@note = para "This Patcher is for use ONLY with Firmware BFB251"
#@note = para "This software does NOT confirm your model at this time."
#@note = para "Hold down the 3 key while powering on the unit to confirm it's version"
@note = para "I take no responsibility for any damanges or misuse."
para "Select your COM port: "

@my_list_box = list_box(
items: ["COM1", "COM2", "COM3", "COM7"], 
width: 120,) 
button "Begin Patching Process" do
port = @my_list_box.text
serial = SerialPort.new("#{port}", 9600)
serial.read_timeout = 200
serial.write("\x50\xBB\xFF\x01\x25\x98\x4D") #contains initialization to program
serial.readlines
serial.write("\x02") #requests firmware version
serial.readlines
serial.write("\x06")
serial.readlines
serial.write("\x58\x1f\xc0\x10\x00\x00\x00\x02\x02\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x34\x01\x80\x00") #contains VHF freqs (\x01\x34\x01\x80)
serial.readlines
serial.write("\x06\x58\x1f\xd0\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x04\x00\x05\x20\x00") #contains UHF freqs (x01\x04\x00\x05\x20)
serial.readlines
serial.write("\x06\x58\x1e\xe0\x10\x20\x20\x56\x46\x4f\x20\x20\x55\x4e\x4c\x4f\x43\x4b\x20\x00\x00") #contains pwr on msg (ASCII)
end
end
```

Comment: Get ride of your @note variables; they do nothing.  Also, you need to figure out how to indent your code.  Any programming text editor will automatically do that for you.  Do not use a normal text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested because Green Shoes installation caused an error on Mac OSX 10.6.8:

```
Shoes.app do

  para "Select your COM port: "
  @current_selection = para "No port selected" 

  my_list_box = list_box(
    items: ["COM1", "COM2", "COM3"], 
    width: 120,
  )

  my_list_box.change do |list_box|
    choice = list_box.text
    @current_selection.text = choice
    @port = choice
  end

end
```

Of course, you can do away with the @current_selection para, and just do `@port = list_box.text`.

You can also specify the change block directly after the list_box() method call:

```
Shoes.app do

  para "Select your COM port: "
  @current_selection = para "No port selected" 

  list_box(
    items: ["COM1", "COM2", "COM3"], 
    width: 120,
  ) do |my_list_box|
    choice = my_list_box.text
    @current_selection.text = choice
    @port = choice
  end

end
```

**Response to comment:**

It sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
Shoes.app do

  para "Select your COM port: "

  @my_list_box = list_box(
    items: ["COM1", "COM2", "COM3"], 
    width: 120,
  ) 

  button "Begin Patching Process" do
    port = @my_list_box.text
    #Do stuff with port here...
  end

end
```

According to the Green Shoes docs, @variables are available throughout the blocks in your app, so you just need to assign the result of calling list_box() to an @variable.

Comment: Still running into the same issues, however I think it's just syntax probably in the way I'm implementing it. I'll come back later to try again and let you know how it turns out. This is so very close. Thanks btw, you've been very helpful here and on past questions I've had.

Comment: @Corrosive, When you say **'port' so that it can be passed to my script**, is your script a separate program from your Shoes app?

Comment: No, it's all in one. Here are a few lines after the button press (push contains AT symbol but the site didn't like that)

    push = button "Begin Patching Process"
    push.click {
 serial = SerialPort.new("#{port}", 9600)
 serial.read_timeout = 200
 serial.write("\x50\xBB\xFF\x01\x25\x98\x4D") 
 }
    end

Comment: Easier to read here: 

    push = button "Begin Patching Process"
    push.click {
 serial = SerialPort.new("#{port}", 9600)
 ##some serial here## 
 }
    end

Comment: @Corrosive, see the addition to my answer.

Comment: I just added more code to the original post.. I'm going to try your suggestion and get back to you

Comment: Added.... I'm getting an error I don't understand.
C:/.../ruby.rb:14:in
`exit_application': super: no superclass method `exit_application' for GLib:Modu
le (NoMethodError)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!
I'll be posting the working code for others to reference.